# RecyclerView's GridLayoutManager - rows Overlap on shorter screens

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have a RecyclerView whose elements needs to be displayed in 4 columns. I do this via GridLayoutManager  as shown below :

```
    mActivityBinding.bwRv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(MysActivityTwo.this, 4);
    mActivityBinding.bwRv.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

With my individual item layout as shown below :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/bw_items_width"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/bw_et_questions"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/bw_et_questions"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bw_et_questions"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:optCardBackgroundColor="@color/dark_font"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

So it has fixed height and width.

It is displayed correctly in Normal bigger screens but in smaller screen, Columns overlap each other. Is there any way I can specify that Normally in larger screens it should pick up 4 Columns but in smaller screens it should wrap somehow and not overlap?

Answer (score 0):

You can define layouts based on screen sizes.Refer this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseSWQuali)

For large screens, you can define a layout in res/layouts/layout-large and for small ones in res/layout.

Comment: Yes I know that I can define using folder such as xxxhdpi or xxhdpi etc. But I want some automatic way for maxColumns visible. That is if Columns are overlapping than resuce number of columns.

Comment: You can check for screen width before defining the layoutManager and define the num of columns accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to Seperate items of Gridview. Create a Class for Spacing

```
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
public class SpacesItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
private int space;
public SpacesItemDecoration(int space) {
    this.space = space;
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view,
                           RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    outRect.left = space;
    outRect.right = space;
    outRect.bottom = space;

    // Add top margin only for the first item to avoid double space between items
    if (parent.getChildLayoutPosition(view) == 0) {
        outRect.top = space;
    } else {
        outRect.top = 0;
    }
}}
```

And set it On your RecyclerView.

```
 int spacingInPixels = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.spacing);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(spacingInPixels));
```

Put it on dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="spacing">2dp</dimen>
```